# Android developer change all app screens language on button click

Tags: android

I know how to use locale and strings.xml for global locale, in addition I created 3 buttons on rhe main activity with 3 different languages on them, how can I switch the whole strings in all screens in one click, how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are many here eager to help, but please show your research effort and what code you tried. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Step1:
Use a preference to store the locale language and country, if you want this language switching is persistent.

Step2:
Try a function like this

```
public void switchLocale(Locale locale) { 
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration(); 
    if (locale != null && !config.locale.equals(locale)) { 
          Locale.setDefault(locale); 
          Configuration conf = new Configuration(config); 
          conf.locale = locale;      
          getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, 
          getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
    } 
  }
```

Step3:
Restart your current activity.

Hope this helps.